# Get all values from a multidimensional array into a single array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

THe array:

```
itemA => value
  itemA1 => value
  itemA2 => value
    itemA11 => value
itemB => value

and so on...
```

How can I get the values gathered like this:

```
[0] => value (from itemA)
[1] => value (from itemA1)
[2] => value (from itemA2)
[3] => value (from itemA11)
[4] => value (from itemB)
...
```

?

Comment: BTW have a look [here](http://davidwalsh.name/flatten-nested-arrays-php) it seems exactly what you need...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By writing your own array function, using [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php) ?
Or, i dont know, but maybe with array_values() ?

edit: i found this:

```
 $a = array(1,2,array(3,4, array(5,6,7), 8), 9); 
 $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a)); 
 foreach($it as $v) { 
   echo $v, " "; 
 }
```

Comment: Great Answer, how did you find it?

Comment: @Iscariot found it on David Walsh's site in a user comment: https://davidwalsh.name/flatten-nested-arrays-php#comment-18807